# How to migrate online data from one hive cluster to another?

Tags: hive

I have tables that are being updates in hive every hour or so, maybe even more frequently. I want to migrate data from one hive cluster to another.

In cassandra there's something called dual proxy and zero downtime migration proxy. Where you set this proxy up to write data to both clusters, and then you just migrate offline data. Eventually you remove this proxy and just write data to the new cluster.

How do we do this in hive?